# Adding a line break in Facebook's og:description using a php lanuage file

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sharer

I am trying to display a line break in the og:description for sharing purposes with Facebook,

but everything i have tried doesnt seem to work.

there are other questions like this on this site but not using a php language file.

The og:description is getting pulled from a language file

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo lang('FBdescription'); ?>"/>
```

here is what i have tried

```
/* Facebook description Title */
'FBdescription' => 'this is my first line <h1></h1> this is my second line',
```

-----and--------

```
/* Facebook description Title */
'FBdescription' => 'this is my first line <br /> this is my second line',
```

-----and--------

```
/* Facebook description Title */
'FBdescription' => 'this is my first line \n this is my second line',
```

-----and--------

```
/* Facebook description Title */
'FBdescription' => 'this is my first line \n\n this is my second line',
```

This has really puzzled me :/

Is there a way to add multiple og:descriptions for a quick fix.?

every update to my code i am clearing the [facebook cahce](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

Comment: Try `'FBdescription' => 'this is my first line \n this is my second line',`

Comment: nope the output is "this is my first line this is my second line"

Comment: Try adding another `\n` then. `'FBdescription' => 'this is my first line \n\n this is my second line',`

Comment: nope the same output.

Comment: Probably because FB thinks you're trying to inject some PHP and manipulate their code. There's always a method to their madness.

Comment: saying that i have checked what there Scrapers sees on my page and its as follows : <meta property="og:description" content="this is my first line \n\n this is my second line test 2">

Comment: See this page => **http://ogp.me/** - you're probably going to find some answers in there. Notice how they're using 2 tags `<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock2.jpg" />` - You probably could do the same with your tag.